# pass variable from scriplet to jsp - null pointer

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Struggling to pass a variable from a scriplet in one jsp to the 'calling jsp'

assetedit.jsp posts a binary stream to upload.jsp.
upload.jsp proceses that stream and determines a filepath which I want to make available in assedit.jsp but the returned value always produces null pointer.

I am obviously doing something fundamentally wrong, I even tried asynch in the post to 'stop' the jsp in case things were happening too fast.

Thoughts appreciated.

assetedit.jsp -

```
//post binary to upload.jsp
$.ajax({
url: '/wz/upload.jsp',
data: decodedstring,
type: 'POST',
contentType: false,
processData: false,
}).done(function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

upload.jsp (some lines removed to make easier to understand -

```
<%
try {
String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/uploads/"); 
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(request.getInputStream());
String nm = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
String filepath = root + "/" + nm;
String realpath = (filepath.substring(filepath.lastIndexOf("/") - 7));
System.out.println("realpath is   "  + realpath);
pageContext.setAttribute("pathtogo", realpath);

}
fos.close();
bis.close();
);
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

assetedit.jsp -

```
<%
String str = request.getAttribute("pathtogo").toString();
System.out.println("pathtogo is   "  + str);
%>
```

also tried (in assetedit.jsp) -

```
<%
        String name=(pageContext.getAttribute("pathtogo").toString()); 
        System.out.println("pathtogo is "+name); 
%>
```

resulting in - Uncaught TypeError: getElemRefs(...) is null

Thoughts appreciated, do I need to do another post in upload.jsp to send pathtogo back to assetedit.jsp?

Ralph

Comment: Please try pageContext.getAttribute("pathtogo"); instead of request.getAttribute

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: getElemRefs(...) is null

Comment: in the first page, when you doSystem.out.println("realpath is   "  + realpath);, what does it print?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use Session Scope, in order to pass appropriate variables between different JSP Pages.

```
pageContext.setAttribute("pathtogo",realPath,PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);  
    
pageContext.getAttribute("pathtogo",PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html

---- Edited ----

ok lets try something else:

upload.jsp

```
session.setAttribute("pathtogo",realPath);
```

assetedit.jsp -

```
<%
String str = (String)session.getAttribute("pathtogo");

System.out.println("pathtogo is   "  + str);
%>
```

or `String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("pathtogo"));`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: getElemRefs(...) is null

Comment: That probably means the value you are storing is null....

Comment: realpath (from System.out.println("realpath is   "  + realpath) in upload.jsp;) is uploads/1607424800198.jpg

Comment: ok @Ralph Try with application scoped then.  Perhaps your jsps dont deal wtih the same session.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: getElemRefs(...) is null. Dont understand this. jsps's are definately same session and application scope may cause issues. Always returns null, seems to not like attributes being set inside scriptlets.

Comment: @Ralph  just curious ralph...are you actually using pathtogo or filetogo? because I see String name=(pageContext.getAttribute("filetogo").toString()); ????

Comment: Apologies, edited original post, using pathtogo. I have now tried application, session and page scope and pathtogo is just not retrievable in assetedit.jsp. I did try and do a post from upload.jsp to assetedit.jsp but that did nothing. Well and truly stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I 'fixed' the issue meantime by putting a return function in the ajax call (which didn't reqiore any attribute settings in either jsp). The returned fielpath could then be split and realpath / pathtogo recovered. Solved by luck rather than judgement. That was 3 weeks work just because Flash is being discontinued.

Comment: Glad you fixed it @Ralph